# Siteminder: Java Agent API

Tags: java, api, siteminder

I want to create an agent object using siteminder r.12. Want to find the values for the below parameters. Where is the value stored?

User-defined connection parameters defined in your code—for example:
    AgentAPI agent = new AgentAPI();
    ServerDef sd = new ServerDef();
    sd.serverIpAddress = POLICY_IP;
    sd.connectionMin = CX_MIN;
    sd.connectionMax = CX_MAX;
    sd.connectionStep = CX_STEP;
     sd.timeout = CX_TIMEOUT;
     sd.authorizationPort = AZ_PORT;
     sd.authenticationPort = AUTH_PORT;
    sd.accountingPort = ACC_PORT;
    InitDef init=new InitDef(AGENT_LOGIN,SHARED_SECRET,false, sd);
    agent.init(init);

Thanks,
navi

Answer (score 1):

To use the AgentApi you will need to know some things about your Policy Server and agent. You will have to find the host address of the Policy Server, the agent name you will use to query the PS, the authorization port and authentication port and the shared secret.

Go here for the spec of the AgentApi:

https://support.ca.com/cadocs/0/CA%20SiteMinder%2012%2052-ENU/Bookshelf_Files/programming-reference/legacy-sm-java-sdk/netegrity/siteminder/javaagent/AgentAPI.html

Answer (score 0):

the parameters you are looking for are related to Host Configuration Object (HCO) and SmHost.conf settings.